# Using parametric plot to plot solution curves for matrices

Tags: plotting

I define three matrices:

```
A1={{-2, -5}, {1, 4}}
A2={{2, 3}, {-1, -2}}
A3={{3, -9}, {2, 3}}
```

Then I plot their solution curves using parametric plot:

```
Grid@Table[{ParametricPlot[A . {x, y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3},
PlotLabel -> Row[{"A = ", A}]]}, {A, {A1, A2, A3}}]
```

But the result, although intriguing is bizarre, it does not look like solution curves at all. Any idea what happened, and how to get solution curves?

Thanks

Comment: What are "solution curves" ? Perhaps `ContourPlot[A1 . {x, y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}]` is what you are looking for?

Comment: You are right, this is what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: You are making a parametric plot with 2 variables. This specifies a area, not a curve. What you see is actually how a rectangle of 6x6 gets deformed by the linear transformation given by A.

Answer (score 1):

Using `Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #4 &}` to draw the line of `A . {x, y}==0`

```
Table[ParametricPlot[A . {x, y}, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #4 &}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive@{Thick, Red}, PlotStyle -> Yellow, 
  PlotLabel -> Row[{"A = ", A}]], {A, {A1, A2, A3}}]
```